# Error copying table data to another. ODBC php

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Help, It seems that i couldn't copy my data from a specific table to another.. I have tried these attempts.

Code 1 :

$queryzx = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM tempmember WHERE userid='$usernamez'");

```
    $usernamexx = odbc_result($queryzx, 'userid');
    $passwordxx = odbc_result($queryzx, 'passwd');
    $ignxx = odbc_result($queryzx, 'usernick');
    $genderxx = odbc_result($queryzx, 'sex');
    $emailxx = odbc_result($queryzx, 'email');

$query = odbc_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO member (userid, usernick, sex, passwd, vip, email) 
                                       VALUES ('$usernamexx', '$ignxx', '$genderxx', '$passwordxx', 1, '$emailxx')");
```

result : error on $query

Code 2 :

```
$queryzx = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM tempmember WHERE userid='$usernamez'");
$resultx = odbc_free_result($queryzx);
while($transf = odbc_fetch_array($resultx))
{
    $usernamexx = $transf['userid'];
    $passwordxx = $transf['passwd'];
    $ignxx = $transf['usernick'];
    $genderxx = $transf['sex'];
    $emailxx = $transf['email'];
$query = odbc_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO member (userid, usernick, sex, passwd, vip, email) 
                                       VALUES ('$usernamexx', '$ignxx', '$genderxx', '$passwordxx', 1, '$emailxx')");
}
```

result : error on $query

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Check if the userid is not autoincrement on member table. Try to echo query and do manually insert to see if it works

Comment: the userid isn't in autoincrement. the 'sex' tabble column is in 'bit' datatype. the rest of them are in varchars.

Comment: You haven't posted the error message. Is it because you found it irrelevant or because you don't know how to get it?

Comment: i added an if(!$query) and it shows the echo i put in it. which does mean that my $query errored.

Comment: Right, error messages are fundamental: check [odbc_errormsg()](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-errormsg.php).

Comment: i just did this to investigate why.
if (!$query) { echo "no.\n";
 odbc_errormsg();}

but the output is just 'no.'

Comment: wait, i must add echo for errormsg. it gave me this error
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '1';

Comment: Now you only need to print the actual SQL query being sent to figure out what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

if `$genderxx` is a bit value , you should use `b` before it like `b'$genderxx'` in `INSERT` statement

Comment: you mean b'$genderxx' = odbc_result($queryzx, 'sex'); ?

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '\';

Comment: oh wait, the vip is in smallint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys. I forced myself to switch $genderxx into varchar. which would be alright in my case.